# In SQL tables, should I, for example, have "é" or should I have "e&acute;"?

Tags: mysql, sql, unicode, character-encoding

I have tried in vain to look up relevant questions. They are beyond my pay scale. I  am not a professional. To explain this a bit more: in the HTML that I wrote, the em dash would be "& #151;" (that space inserted so it would not show up as an actual em dash). It ended up in the tables (someone else was doing that work) as "—". Those are not showing up correctly when searches are done using PHP. I only get the image with a question mark. I do have my SQL account set to Unicode.

Comment: A couple years ago i wrote a website with PHP with MySql, i just let the data goes to the table as it's inserted by the user, and when it's called again everything worked just fine.

Comment: All of the data in my tables is inserted by me. There are no user accounts. The tables exist only to allow the users to search them.

Comment: well... I guess it's the same thing, only line breaks must be entered as the unicode form, everything else will be fine. i still have 3 hours before going back home, if i don't forget i'll search for that project again and see if i have some codes for you to avoid errors.

Comment: Either way, I have the text in the tables not using the codes, and they're not showing up the same when searches are done. If all the people here voting this question down were as capable of writing clearly as they are of clicking and scrolling performing slave labor for their "tech" giant overlords, that would be great. Then again, simple issues like this are often not dealt with well by programmers/ developers precisely b/c they don't care.

Comment: I've tried using "e&acute;" for example and it seems to show up fine, but I'm not sure if that's because of my browser's specs or my computer's specs. The question of course is what actually would result in the correct result most of the time.

Comment: '_If all the people here voting this question down ..._'. Your question may be downvoted (fwiw, I didn't) for:  1.) It's rather a design issue but a question of programming/developing, and you don't inform us about your design objectives. 2.) You don't show code, data, or error messages. BTW: Imho, issues related to charset encoding are hardly ever _simple_ (people tend to think they are as it's 'just about some text').

Comment: Are these forums supposed to be only for design? For laypersons, either way, I'm not sure where the line is between that and programming. I don't have any code. I'm trying to figure out what kind of code to use first.

Comment: @Kaw - Stackoverflow leans toward coding, not design.  However, many questions lie in a gray area between the two.  Or the answer to a coding problem is to redesign.  Or...  Since this Question has not been closed for being in the wrong forum (dba.stackexchange.com being a common other place), "we" agree that it fits here.  Downvoting can happen for other reasons.

Comment: @Kaw - Respondents on this collection of forums have 5 not-very-relevant ways to "close" a question, so sometimes they just downvote instead.  (Click on _close_ to see the 5.)  Your question falls into the "opinion based" category, but I think that your question (and some others) deserve the opinion of those who have tackled the question.  I usually answer questions as tiny 'teaching moments' for the Asker _and_ those listening in.

Comment: If you go to the home page, there is no information about these elaborate rules you're mentioning. There are questions, encouraging other questions, esp. in that they're not organized in any systematic way. The help page says nothing about this site being for coding not designing. And I have no idea whether my question would be considered to belong to one or the other. To be frank, given the way that the Web/ internet tech has gone in the last 10 years or so, it's laughable for coders/ designers to demand adherence to rules that they don't bother to share or follow themselves.

Answer (score 1):

*Take a philosophical stand:*  The datastore (database table) should contain *data*, not some special encoding of the data.

The "data" is `é`

When you display that in HTML, you might need to convert it to `e&acute;`.  However, all modern browsers don't have a problem *if* `é` is encoded UTF-8.

If you choose to use "html entities", then have your application do the conversion *after* fetching `é` from the table.  PHP has the function `htmlentities()` specifically for that task.

But, I still have not addressed what byte(s) are in the table to represent `é`.  These days, you 'should' use UTF-8 (aka MySQL's utf8mb4).  That would be two hex bytes `C3A9`, which can be discovered using `SELECT HEX(col) ...`.  If you use the old default, latin1, the hex would show `C9`.

A related question is whether you should store html 'tags' or construct the html on the fly after fetching the data.  So, let me give you three philosophies; you pick which to apply:

- The table contains pure data; formatting, etc, is done after fetching and before delivering to the user's browser.
- The table contains an 'opaque' image of what needs to be sent to the browser -- complete with tags, entities, etc.  With this approach, you may as well call it a `BLOB`, not `TEXT`.
- Some compromise between those.  Note: The use of CSS can avoid too much hard-coding of formatting before storing into the database.

Also, the first choice is much cleaner for searching.  This may lead you to pick it.  However, another approach is to have two columns -- one aimed at delivering mostly-formatted ouput; the other for searching (tags removed, no entities, etc); it would be mostly text, but you probably could not generate a web page (with links, paragraphs, etc) from it.

**é -- different strokes for different folks**

- `é` in latin1 (not advised) hex E9, 1 byte
- `é` in utf8 C3A9 2 bytes
- `\u00E9` -- Unicode codepoint -- 6 bytes
- `&eacute;` -- html entity (see PHP's `htmlentities()`) -- 8 bytes
- `%C3%A9` -- PHP's `urlencode()` (for URLs) -- 6 bytes

**Responding to Comments**

If `entries_lists`, `entries_languages`, and `authors_entries` are many:many mapping tables, please consider the several optimizations mentioned [*here*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table).

Do not use `utf8_encode`.  Instead, figure out what caused them not to be encoded correctly, and/or not displayed correctly.  Start by

```
echo bin2hex($record['author']);

SELECT name, HEX(name) FROM authors WHERE ...
```

for some author with an accented letter.

Comment: Yes, I'd do the first option. As far as I know, I've got my whole thing set to UTF-8.

Comment: I've got a lot of data with the special characters as they are, not codes. This would mean I need to do the PHP "htmlentities"? Does this go in the same php file as the other search commands?

Comment: @Kaw - Does my addition answer your question?

Comment: You have to realize I do no understand PHP, and, secondly, many of the tasks to which these PHP functions seem to have been designated are beyond my purview.

I have data in tables with, for example, é, among the characters. Many of them. They are showing up as question marks currently. If I put them in the tables as & eacute; then the browser will show them correctly but the user cannot search for that unless he types in & eacute; as well. 
So I need to know what to put into my index.php document to make the é show up correctly if, for example, a user searches for "Jose."

Comment: The "question mark" problem is a common one, and it has been addressed many times on this forum..  `é` is sufficiently representative; em-dash would act similarly.  If you don't understand PHP, you probably need someone to work one-on-one with you.  A forum is too slow and clumsy.

Comment: Yes, you're right about that. I live in a town with a fairly small, new community of coders/ designers, and the one professional to whom I've spoken about working with me hasn't been communicative.

Comment: I am now able to get most special characters to display properly. This was done by a simple change to my functions.php page (the other PHP pages I have are db.php and index.php). As such: adding "utf8_encode" to the "echo" statements: e.g. "echo "<h3>".utf8_encode($record['author'])."</h3>";" However, it seems that characters in the Latin-1 Supplement are not showing up correctly.

Comment: Well...  Using any kind of encode/decode is only masking the real problem.  Please provide the output from `echo bin2hex($record['author']);`.  (And tell me what `$record['author']` _should_ be.)

Comment: OK, what I think you're asking is: the output, for example, is "K?ng Z?" instead of "Kǒng Zǐ". You can see more examples at greaterbooks.com/search/ if you look at Chinese-language and Russian-language entries b/c those languages use the caron symbol, a major example of what's in the Latin-1 Supplement but not the Basic.

Comment: @Kaw - True for "latin1"  MySQL's latin1/2/5/7 do not have those two characters.  (Nor did I find them in the rest of the single-byte character sets.)  However, there are readily available in utf8 and utf8mb4.  There, `ǒ` and `ǐ` are hex `C792` and `C790`.

Comment: I tried replacing the "utf8" in the PHP code that I provided above with "utf8mb4"; that doesn't work.

Comment: (The characters in question are identical in `utf8` and `utf8mb4`.)

Comment: Do you have suggestions for a more effective "masking [of] the realm problem", i.e. what should I put in those "echo" lines instead of "utf8" to make the carons display propertly?

Comment: @Kaw - The `echo bin2hex...` is to help me figure out _where_ the problem is.

Comment: Is this an actual attempt to deal with issues, or merely half-assed attempts to find cultural meaning in being unwelcoming to those without requisite experience or education, the details of which knowledge are only displayed fittingly, usually in verbal sparring matches among those assuming that they have such knowledge?

Comment: @Kaw - Rather get in the religious war of which forum a question belongs in, I monitor both the one and dba.stackexchange.  I'm still willing to help with "K?ng Z?", but I need some information from you.  There are 4-6 different points in the code that need to say utf8/utf8mb4 in order to avoid question marks or black diamonds or truncation or Mojibake.  And that doesn't even cover the "htmlentities".

Comment: Here's the functions.php file (first part)

Comment: <?php  
 include 'db.php';


 function users(){
  global $conn;
  $select_users = $conn->query('select * from lists');
  while($users = $select_users->fetch_assoc() ){
   echo "<option value='".$users['id']."'>".$users['name']."</option>";
  } 
 }

 function languages(){
  global $conn;
  $select_lan = $conn->query('select * from languages');
  while($lan = $select_lan->fetch_assoc() ){
   echo "<option value='".$lan['id']."'>".$lan['language']."</option>";
  } 
 }

Comment: function search(){
  global $conn;
  $user_id = $_POST['user'];
  $lan     = $_POST['language'];
  $title   = $_POST['title'];
  $author  = $_POST['author'];

Comment: $select = $conn->query("select a.name as author,t.title,e.*,l.name,lan.language from titles as t inner join entries as e on e.id = t.entry_id inner join entries_lists as eu on e.id = eu.entry_id inner join entries_languages as el on e.id = el.entry_id inner join authors_entries as ae on e.id = ae.entry_id inner join lists as l on l.id = eu.list_id inner join languages as lan on lan.id = el.language_id inner join authors as a on a.id = ae.author_id where l.id = '$user_id' AND lan.id = '$lan' AND t.title LIKE '%$title%' AND a.name LIKE '%$author%' ");
  $count = $select->num_rows;

Comment: if($count < 1){
   echo '<h2>No Record Found</h2>';
   die();
  }
  while($record = $select->fetch_assoc() ){

Comment: echo "<div class='col-sm-8' style='border:1px solid #ccc; margin-top: 20px;'>";
   echo "<h3>".utf8_encode($record['author'])."</h3>";
   echo "<h4>".utf8_encode($record['title'])."</h4>";
   echo "<p>".utf8_encode($record['date_language_description'])."</p>";
   echo "<p>Language: ".utf8_encode($record['language'])."</p>";
   echo "<p>List: ".utf8_encode($record['name'])."</p></div>";
   
  }
 }

Comment: @Kaw - I added some more.